# Pass variable from $routeProvider to View

Tags: angularjs

How can I pass a variable from `$routeProvider` to a view file:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/send-money', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/send-money.html',
      controller: 'PageCtrl'
    })
    .when('/receive-money', {
      someURL: 'goToSomePage',
      templateUrl: 'partials/receive-money.html',
      controller: 'PageCtrl'
    })
}]);
```

As you can notice on top: 
`.when('/receive-money')` i have declared (`someURL: 'goToSomePage'`)
but `.when('/send-money')` i have not declared (`someURL`)

Below is the code that I would like to make it work, without taking help of controller. Is that possible ? even I am not sure something like `ng-if="someURL"` will work.

```
<div ng-if="someURL">
  <a ng-href="someURL" class="nav-back"> <i class="ico-back"></i> </a>
<div>
```

Comment: You will need controller in this case.

Comment: as said, I don't want to use controller for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use controller you can use `run` block to pass a reference to route service into $rootScope, from where you could check if current route has property `someURL`:

```
app.run(function($route, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$route = $route;
});
```

Now in template you could use `$route.current` in `ngIf`:

```
<div ng-if="$route.current.someURL">
    <a ng-href="someURL" class="nav-back"><i class="ico-back"></i></a>
</div>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3XUl0QprIAj1PcnnHx9Q?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @dfsq, the only change that I did to make your code work was: rather ng-href="someURL" i had changed it to ng-href="$route.current.someURL". Am i doing something wrong or does my change make sense ?

Comment: You can use `$route.current.someURL` in ngHref, it will work too.